# Wordpress troubles updating options

Tags: php, wordpress

Sometimes I have troubles getting or updating my options. I have an option `gtdp_games`, which I set to 'test' previously via `update option` function. Later I was trying to update it like this

```
update_option('gtdp_games', '[100,313,582,704,755,800]');
```

But I was getting a wrong result on the other page, so I started testing and it was driving me mad:

```
update_option('gtdp_games', '[100,313,582,704,755,800]');
var_dump(get_option('gtdp_games')); //string(25) "[100,313,582,704,755,800]"

//so this was fine until I try to get this var from DB

global $wpdb;
$q = "SELECT option_value FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name='gtdp_games'";
var_dump($wpdb->get_var($q)); //string(4) "test"
```

I somehow made it work by updating this option to something else before updating it to my value

```
update_option('gtdp_games', 'loremipsum');
update_option('gtdp_games', '[100,313,582,704,755,800]');
```

This way I managed to have the same result using `get_option` and `wpdb->get_var`, but it's so wrong, I don't get why it keeps happening randomly in different parts of my site.

And now, on the other page I'm trying to get this value through `get_option` and I'm getting 'test', I've never seen anything like this

```
global $wpdb;
$q = "SELECT option_value FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name='gtdp_games'";
var_dump($wpdb->get_var($q), get_option('gtdp_games')); 
//string(25) "[100,313,582,704,755,800]"
//string(4) "test"
```

It's a multisite, but if I dump current blog id, it's correct. Has anybody seen something like this? Any ideas why this issue may occur? It just happens sometimes on different sites in my network and in different places.

Comment: Likely some sort of caching issue. If you check the source code of `get_option`, you'll see that it uses WP caching functionality in several places.

Comment: Do you have memcached enabled?